# Is there a way to run pure scala code in a script tag

Tags: scala.js, scalatags

Using the scalatags script tag I know I can define the following:

```
script("console.log('Running javascript code')")
```

But is there a way I can rather pass pure scala code instead? So something like the following:

```
script(println("Running scala code now"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible.

You can achieve the same effect in a different way, by exporting a top-level function with the Scala code you want to run, then generate a script that calls that function:

```
object Exports {
  @JSExportTopLevel("dynamicScriptCode")
  def code(): Unit =
    println("Running Scala code now")
}

...

script("dynamicScriptCode();")
```

Comment: Yes I was thinking I could do it that way, but I would need to pass parameters that are specific to every call. So for example say the code() method above has to take a js.Object as a parameter. Would there be a way to pass this object "out and back in again"?

Comment: That becomes tricky. If you only ever have one active instance of that, you can store it in a `var` in `Exports`. Otherwise, you should `JSON.stringify` the object to pass it as a parameter to the record function, which should therefore take a `js.Object` as parameter.